# Shadow artefacts with aframe directional light

Tags: aframe

I have a .glb model and I'm trying to get nice dynamic shadows working.

I've played around with all the settings and read the docs but this is the best I can do and I'm getting unpleasant artefacts.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve better results?

Demo: http://planetvr.shop/orchid-1.html

Comment: Ah, looks like it's related to "shadow acne" as described here:

https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/2192/cause-of-shadow-acne

Comment: Perhaps bake the shadows in like Blender?

Comment: Thanks ngokevin. As I wanted this model for scenes with dynamic lighting I've ended up baking in the ambient occlusion and tweaking the shadow bias. Not perfect but I'm happy for now. Link above updated.

Comment: Looks beautiful to me :)